# How to Find First Order Derivatives of S&P500 Data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod, rcharts, derivative

I'm working on trying to pull data data for stock ticker name S&P500 for the last year. So from Jan 1st 2015 to Jan 1st 2016. I want to find the first order derivatives of the closing price and see if there is any white noise. Does anyone know how I can do this? any help would be appreciated

This is the r code i got so far to get the stock data and do some calcuations.

```
library(quantmod); 
getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo"); 
SP500<-GSPC['2015-01-01::2016-01-01']; 
time(SP500);
SP500$GSPC.time<-time(SP500);
derivative<-diff(SP500$GSPC.Close)/diff(SP500$GSPC.time);
derivative;
chartseries(derivative);
plot(y, main="GWN of first order derivative of S&P500 Closing Prices ",
type="l", xlab="time",ylab="y(t)", col="blue", lwd=2);
abline(h=c(0,-0.05,0.05), lwd=2, lty=c("solid","dotted","dotted"), 
col=c("green", "red", "red"));
```

This is what I got so far. I have no idea if I did this correctly so any help would be great!

Comment: diff(SP500$GSPC.Close) ?

Comment: i did something similar to that but i'm trying to calculate white noise.